# How to access external URL in salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger, callout

I am new in salesforce - I need to hit my product URL(http://hostName:9090/product/HTTPListener?ExecuteProcess=Create_PO) to call certain workflow from salesforce.
I did few things with Apex trigger and Apex class but that is not working
Appex Class -

```
public class MyHelloWorld {

    @future(callout=true)
    Public static void myMethod()
    {
     System.debug('inside myMethod...'); 


             // Instantiate a new http object
            Http h = new Http();

            // Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (GET) as well as the endpoint
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint('http://hostName:9090/product/HTTPListener?ExecuteProcess=Create_PO');
            req.setMethod('GET');

            // Send the request, and return a response
            HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

     //do your callout logic here... System.debug('exiting myMethod...'); 
     } 
     }
```

Apex trigger -

```
trigger TestOne on eQCustomObejct__c (after insert) {

MyHelloWorld.myMethod();


}
```

Not working - Means my process is not executed
Sorry guys i cant write in comment.
hostName -  i Passed proper IP for my machine.
Entry in network - Yes i done with Network access entry.

Comment: Are you bound to using a trigger, for your use case, maybe the process builder would be more suitable? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_overview.htm&type=0 you can invoce an apex class on record modification/creation. I am assuming this is the case?

Comment: Have you added the external URL in remote site setting?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to clarify what you mean by "not working".

Comment: Is the actual value of `hostName` something that Salesforce could resolve to a public IP address?